# google vision Barcode for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, barcode-scanner

I used Barcode cocoapods framework for ios. Unfortunately in xcode logs it says `Instantiated (null)`. I used this framework embedded to other language.

Why it keeps saying `Instantiated (null)`? is there's any factor that this object can't be instantiated? Or there's a proper way on how to instantiate this object.

```
GMVDetector *barcodeDetector = [GMVDetector detectorOfType:GMVDetectorTypeBarcode options:nil];
```

Comment: Are you find any solution?

Comment: Instead of using coocoapods  for Barcode scanner. I used AVFoundation framework. Try to look AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate